# orWhere clause allows duplicities

Tags: php, laravel

My code is not working and I know it´s because of the **orwhere** clauses.

This is for an item list, and the objective is to avoid duplicates. So if 'nombre', 'codigo_interno' or 'codigo_comercial' already exists in the list, they should not appear again. If you type the attribute 'nombre' and it has been added to the list, it won´t appear in the drop-down list to add items, but **codigo_interno** and **codigo_comerial** do, meaning that the clause **->where('nombre' , 'like' , '%'.$request->busqueda.'%')** is working, but the **orWhere** are not.

Could you tell me whats wrong with it?

```
public function findArticulo(Request $request)
{

    $id = $request->id;

    $articulos = Articulo::query()->select([
        'id',
        'codigo_interno',
        'codigo_comercial',
        'impuestos_venta',
        'impuestos_compra',
        'nombre',
        'descripcion',
        'status'])
        ->where('status','activo')
        ->whereNotIn('id', function($query)use($id){
            $query->select('articulo_id')
                ->from('listas_precios_articulos')
                ->where('lista_precio_id', $id)
                ->whereNotIn('estatus', ['eliminado']);
        })
        ->where('nombre' , 'like' , '%'.$request->busqueda.'%')
        ->orWhere('codigo_interno' , 'like' , '%'.$request->busqueda.'%')
        ->orWhere('codigo_comercial' , 'like' , '%'.$request->busqueda.'%')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

    return response()->json($articulos,200);
}
```

Comment: It might help if you tell us what you expect the SQL from this to look like. Do you want the `LIKE` conditions grouped as in the provided answer?

Comment: If it works, yes, but if there is a way to improve I will be more than glad to learn it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you should make a block with three conditions

```
$id = $request->id;
$busqueda = $request->busqueda;
$articulos = Articulo::query()->select([
        'id',
        'codigo_interno',
        'codigo_comercial',
        'impuestos_venta',
        'impuestos_compra',
        'nombre',
        'descripcion',
        'status'])
        ->where('status','activo')
        ->whereNotIn('id', function($query)use($id){
            $query->select('articulo_id')
                ->from('listas_precios_articulos')
                ->where('lista_precio_id', $id)
                ->whereNotIn('estatus', ['eliminado']);
        })
        ->where(function($query) use (busqueda){
          $query->where('nombre' , 'like' , '%'.busqueda .'%')
                ->orWhere('codigo_interno' , 'like' , '%'.busqueda .'%')
                ->orWhere('codigo_comercial' , 'like' , '%'.busqueda.'%');
         })
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

It should generated somthing like ... AND (? OR ? OR ?)
But you must check that you can pass $request->busqueda in use or you can do normal variable to pass in it.